# Remove linear layout from custom textView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-xml

I have a custom textView, which placed inside of LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="Only on 22 of July, 2019"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And CustomTimerView with some logic

```
class CustomTimerView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attributeSet) {
    private var textView: TextView

    init {
        LinearLayout.inflate(context, R.layout.customTimer_layout, this)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.timerView)
    }

    fun setDates(ob: Promo) {
        val startDate = getStartDate(ob)
        val endDate = getEndDate(ob)

        if (startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            textView.text = getInDifferentMonths(context!!, ob)
        } else {
            if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                textView.text = getOnlyOneDay(context!!, ob)
            } else {
                textView.text = getInOneMonth(context!!, ob)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviosly, LinearLayout is useless. But how can I remove this without moving my textView data to code and to child in other layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the linear layout with the textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    tools:text="Only on 22 of July, 2019"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    />
```

About the class, I don't know if I understood correctly, but I'll give it a guess:

```
class CustomTimerView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : TextView(context, attributeSet) {

    init {
        TextView.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_timer_layout, null)
    }

    fun setDates(ob: Promo) {
        val startDate = getStartDate(ob)
        val endDate = getEndDate(ob)

        if (startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            this.text = getInDifferentMonths(context!!, ob)
        } else {
            if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                this.text = getOnlyOneDay(context!!, ob)
            } else {
                this.text = getInOneMonth(context!!, ob)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking more about class. How to inflate textView in CustomTimerView? I've got only errors

Comment: For some reasons, textView styles doesn't applyes. How it can be possible? I have only deffault textColor, not that I've mentioned

Comment: @Strangelove I think it would be better to open another question about the the style if you haven't done it yet.